# Google sheets Nested query on a multi column query result

Tags: google-sheets

This is best explained with an example:

The following sheets:

**Trades:**

[image]

**Items:**

[image]

**Query:**

[image]

The query in cell A3:

```
=Query(Trades,"Select B, C where A = 0")
```

What im hoping to do is then further query the itemID (only the first result column) to return its ItemName and combine that result with the ItemQty (second column).

is this possible to do?

Comment: For this to be a question / answer that lasts for years (the goal here at stackoverflow) please try to make it self-contained. Linking to a google doc isn't going to last very long.

Comment: @DylanMcNamee done!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) - it's how to do database-like queries / joins on spreadsheet tables.

I think I got what you're after here:

[image]